# How to make post-Lion Finders find special directory . and ..?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Before OS X 10.7, you can navigate to the parent directory in Finder using Go to (`Shift+Command+G`) to the special directory `..`.

However, since Lion Finder is no longer able to do this and gives he error message `The folder can't be found`.

Is there a way to enable Finder to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to go 'up' in Finder, you can use the keyboard shortcut ⌘↑.

This is the equivalent of `cd ..` which is what you would achieve by 'going' to the `..` folder. Alternatively, you can select **Go** → **Enclosing folder** from the menu bar. A custom keyboard shortcut can be assigned to this menu item using App Shortcuts.